# Is it possible to use face traking on iPhones without a truedepth camera ?xcode

Tags: xcode, arkit

Is it possible to build a dietz model using only a front - facing camera without a TrueDepth camera . I read somewhere that it is possible . When trying to launch a build from the apl on the iPhone 7: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/content_anchors/tracking_and_visualizing_faces returns an error that the device is not supported .

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible that this idea can be implemented, but the quality of facial tracking using just info coming from single RGB camera (without depth data) will be of the worst quality. If the iPhone 7 had two front RGB cameras, then the depth map could be obtained based on the [disparity](https://www.andreasjakl.com/how-to-apply-stereo-matching-to-generate-depth-maps-part-3/) map. But having only one camera, it's a pointless effort.